# vtiger 6.4 google sync no access control

Tags: cors, google-calendar-api, contacts, vtiger

hy everyone!

got everything almost working with synchronization of vtiger ver 6.4 and google calendar & contacts api.
there remains one problem: it's not synchronizing because of a

```
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access."
```

Although domain is registered, confirmed as property, client-id & key are working.

Question one: is it a problem of vtiger or a problem of google-authorization?
Question two: anybody knows a solution to allow this CORS?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `crm/modules/Webforms/capture.php`

Add:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
```