# How to get JSON with jQuery from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

I have a little page and I need to get JSON from another domain. If make this:

```
  $.get( "http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    alert( "Load was performed." );
  });
```

I get an error. I understand why it throws this error, but I don`t know how to aviod it. **I have not acces to the server.**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I also tried to use JSONP, but as I understand in that case server should wrap response with callback function, because I got a SyntaxError.

Is it possible to make this request with JSONP?
I tried

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "logResults"
  });

  function logResults(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

But got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

JSON is valid, I checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err . There are number of other question about it.

Comment: The Server does not allow requests coming from other domains apart its own. This is a Server Side configuration and you can not change it without access to the Server. Check out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: whether http://dev.frevend.com/json/users.json is under your control ? @arthur

Comment: No. And that is strange, because I'ts my task for a job and I thought that I`m missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow access in your project configuration. 
Below site has more information

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONP in jquery for this purpose [JSONP reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score -2):

Try to add a header into your PHP file which is responsible for executing every request.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: Quoting OP: `I have not acces to the server`

Comment: Mr. @A. Wolff: How could you mark it not useful as OP clearly mentioned that **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**