# How to Fix No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I know the question has been asked many time but i still didn't find the solution.
Am having a cross domain error when i tried to communicate with my API from the client. I don't know if
there's something am missing here.

`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `http://localhost:28184/Customer/AddCustomer`.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `http://localhost:28189` is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Ajax call:

```
 function AddCompany()
 {
   var companyModel = {
      ----------
 }

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({    
    url: BaseUrl + "Customer/AddCustomer",
    type: "POST",
    withCredentials: false,    
    dataType: "Jason",
    cach: false,
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: companyModel,
    success: function(data){
       alert("Company has been successfully registered");
    }       
 });
}
```

API controller:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Fleet_API.Models;

namespace Fleet_API.Controllers
{
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("Api/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("AddCustomer")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool>AddCompany(CustomerModel model)
    {
         ------------------------
    }
}
}
```

Hosts file from windows

```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   #    127.0.0.1       localhost
   #    ::1             localhost
```

Comment: is xxxx the same xxxx?

Comment: @JaromandaX i don't understand what you please. can you please rephrase your solution

Comment: No it is not the same.. let me update it

Comment: check what headers are coming for the request - I can't make it any simpler for a web developer

Comment: `No it is not the same` - good, because if it were, then CORS wouldn't be required - check your developer tools network tab, see what repsonse headers come in for the `Customer/AddCustomer` request - verify you are actually getting the CORS headers as required

Comment: Can you please give me a direction on were to find it. I guess you refering to Ctrl + Fn + F12 which is console.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins)

Comment: Developer Tools are tools for web developers to help them develop for the interweb - hope that helps

Comment: I will go through the document and hopefully i will get the solution as i have been stuck for two days now

Comment: @Mihir After reading the document you sent. I can simply confirm that i have done everything. the same way as the tutorial. Please help

Comment: @JaromandaX  can you please give me another suggestion i have tried but still it doesn't hit the API

Comment: `dataType: "Jason"` is that a typo just here, or is that your actual code? should be `json`

Comment: For now i can say no because it is not heating the API. how do i give it instructions?

Comment: Let me change the spelling and see if it will make the difference

Comment: @JaromandaX i have changed Jason to jason and still i doesn't work. Please help am really behind because of this error. maybe other possible solution

Comment: `json` `json` `json` there is no `a`

Comment: `For now i can say no because it is not heating the API` - then what is giving you the CORS error???

Comment: for fun try `method: "POST"` instead of `type: "POST"` and `cache: false,` instead of `cach: false` (notice the e in cache) and comment out/remove the `crossDomain: true,` altogether

Comment: getting this error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:28184/Customer/AddCustomer. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:28189' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: None of the solution above its working.

Comment: I don't know .NET that well ... but ... `RoutePrefix("Api/Customer")` ... `[Route("AddCustomer")]` ... you call using `/Customer/AddCustomer` with no hint of `Api` in the path - again, I don't know the .NET very well, but it looks awfully suspicious

Comment: Just read up on it, and, I think you'll need to call that using `/Api/Customer/AddCustomer` rather than just `/Customer/ApiCustomer`

Comment: I have other pages working fine without any problem. this is my first time being stuck in like this.

Comment: what is the baseurl value ?

Comment: are u using chrome ?  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err

Comment: also, the data type should be  dataType: 'jsonp'

Comment: @FakeisMe its a global url to the API

Comment: @FakeisMe I disagree with you because i have application i have developed previously and i have use json  as a datatype not p.