# Oracle Apex "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: javascript, oracle, https, oracle-apex, payfort

```
$.post("https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage", function(data, status){
  data = 'es';
  status = 'es';
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

});
```

i am trying to go to this link in oracle apex  but always have error:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

can anyone help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err

Comment: did you find the solution

Answer (score -2):

**From stackoverflow** @MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob answer

[Just download chrom extension CORS or hack chrome shortcut as below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

> This is not a fix for production or when application has to be shown to the client, this is only helpful when UI and Backend **development**  are on different **servers** and in production they are actually on same server. For example: While developing UI for any application if there is a need to test it locally pointing it to backend server, in that scenario this is the perfect fix. ***For production fix, CORS headers has to be added to the backend server to allow cross origin access.***

The easy way is to just add the extension in google chrome to allow access using CORS.

(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

Just enable this extension whenever you want allow access to no **'access-control-allow-origin'** header request.

**Or**

In Windows, paste this command in **run** window

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

this will open a new **chrome** browser which allow access to no **'access-control-allow-origin'** header request.