# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not sending from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-headers, cors

Good day everybody!

Examined a lot of questions here with a similar problems but they quite different and nothing works.
There is problem with third-party resource that author of question not controlling, in my case I am forcibly send header from server but receive nothing:
[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288)

I have a problem with CORS requests. Here is my JS (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://domain.com/module/api/storeData.php",
    data: 'data='+results,
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(msg){

        if(msg=="Ok")
        {
            $("#resultsPane").append ("Results successfully sent.");
        } else {
            $("#resultsPane").append (msg);
        }

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorT)
    {
       $("#resultsPane").append ("AJAX error: "+status+": "+errorT);
    }
});
```

Very begining of PHP:

```
<?php
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But result is (in console):

> jquery.js:10254 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/module/api/storeData.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Response headers:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 13 Oct 2016 13:19:23 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
```

AJAX errors in browser:

> AJAX error: error: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://domain.com/module/api/storeData.php'.

Does someone know what could going wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` Note you should consider specifying specific hosts to allow.

Comment: You are using `header` wrong. http://php.net/header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err)

Comment: Jon Stirling, Thank a lot!
Really, my miss. Could you please post it as answer to make me able accept it? Thank you!

Comment: This is valid question only, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike various other functions and methods out in the wild where you expect to set items as `key, value` as separate parameters, [header](http://php.net/header) does not. Instead it expects that the entire string of the header line you want to set is the first param.

I.e.

```
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Please do note you should consider specifying specific hosts to allow strictly, rather than allowing any access for security reasons.

Comment: Okay. I really would like to know what the downvote is due to. If there is something wrong, please tell me so I can fix it. Thanks.