# Ajax upload image in localhost PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an `input` file in HTML to upload an image

`<input type="file" id="upload-image">`

I want to upload my image to my local Apache webserver with AJAX like this

```
$('#upload-image').change(function(e){
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
            return;
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file);
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/upload.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

I already moved my `upload.php` to `/var/www/html/`, and when I access it on browser, it does exist on my local webserver. But when I try to upload my image, the browser throws this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/upload.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

This is my `upload.php`:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
?>
```

I thought I already added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header then it would work. How can I make it work?

Comment: And you're running everything on a webserver, like wamp, easyphp etc.

Comment: Read my answer here, maybe it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err/38000615#38000615

Comment: @dkruchok Thank you. It does send. But I don't know why my `form_data` is still completely empty while `file` is not null when I `console.log` both of them

Comment: need to properly implement CORS and not check for files during OPTIONS request