# jquery trigger an external api

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="application/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#btnUsingjQuery').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345",
                 dataType: 'jsonp',
                 success: function (results) {
                     window.location.href = "www.google.com";
                 }
             });
         });
     });
     </script>
```

above are my jquery code which connect to a external api,no matter success or fail it will redirect to google.com.

i faced error after click the button : **Refused to execute script from API because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**
tried change type="application/javascript" still but facing the issue.
any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set it to `json`, you will see error, which means that you don't have permission to access to that `API`. I think if you want to use Google Map Api, you need to register and get a token for accessing to the API.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnUsingjQuery">Click</button>

<script type="application/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#btnUsingjQuery').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345",
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (results) {
                     window.location.href = "www.google.com";
                 }
             });
         });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ,getting this error...

Answer (score 0):

you try this....

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#btnUsingjQuery').click(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=12345",
                     dataType: 'jsonp',
                     success: function (results) {
                         window.location='https://www.google.co.in';
                     }
                 });
             });
         });
    </script>
```

i mean just add

```
window.location='https://www.google.co.in';
```

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ,getting this error.....

Comment: just check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err