# flask jquery GET 404

Tags: jquery, python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I'm playing with jQuery in Flask and have been making use of a simple example I found on [runnable](http://code.runnable.com/UiPhLHanceFYAAAP/how-to-perform-ajax-in-flask-for-python)  of adding two numbers together.

I'm using Flask-Appbuilder and have a view all setup to display the template, which works fine. I included the jQuery code into the template and it displays what it should.

On the Flask side I created the View, and the functions in the view to render the template and to receive the variables in the jQuery GET request.

When I click the jQuery link on the template to add the two number together, I see a 404 error in the python **console**.

```
[07/Apr/2017 09:48:53] "GET /_add_numbers?a=1&b=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here's what I have in my **template**:

```
{% extends "appbuilder/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/_add_numbers', {
          a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
          b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
        }, function(data) {
          $("#result").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">How To Manage JSON Requests</h3>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div>
      <p>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="a"> +
    <input type="text" size="5" name="b"> =
    <span id="result">?</span>
    <p><a href="javascript:void();" id="calculate">calculate server side</a>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

My **flask** view looks like this:

```
class MyView(BaseView):
    default_view = 'sale'

    @expose('/sale', methods=['GET'])
    @has_access
    def sale(self):
        return self.render_template('sale.html')

    @expose('/_add_numbers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @has_access
    def add_numbers(self):
        a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
        b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
        return jsonify(result=a + b)
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

GET Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN4wg.jpg

POST Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJC1Q.jpg

Comment: I've never used FAB before but would suspect that the `@has_access` decorators are interfering somehow. Does it work if you remove them?

Comment: I removed it and still have the same 404 in the console when I click the link

Comment: Well, like I say, I don't know about FAB. If you're just experimenting with jQuery, it might be easier to use standard Flask routes and views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using flask-appbuilder and the [syntax suggested](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#baseview) is:

> ```
> class MyView(BaseView):
>     route_base = "/myview"
>
>     @expose('/method1/<string:param1>')
>     def method1(self, param1):
>         # do something with param1
>         # and return it
>         return param1
> ```

Which results in a url looking like this: `http://<your_host>/myview/method1/<awaiting string param>`

That is probably what interferes with your URL.

---

**A bit more thorough explanation:**

GET request tries to locate the `/_add_numbers?a=1&b=1` URL which as far as your back-end is concerned does not match any exposed URL.
You should try defining your exposed URL as follows:

```
@expose('/_add_numbers?<int:a>&<int:b>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

*If `flask-appbuilder` gives you problems, try to experiment with the default flask and see if that works for you, then with that knowledge move forward.*

---

**Note:**

Typically this is not a **GET** but a **POST** request.

You can try a simple [`jquery $.post()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) call instead of `getJSON`:

```
$.post('http://localhost:5000/_add_numbers',{
    a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
    b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
}, function(data) {
    $("#result").text(data.result);
});
```

The `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error has been referred and answered thoroughly in those posts:

- [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: When I change to a POST, then I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` screenshot -  http://imgur.com/a/cSehL