# How do I make an HTTP request to bitstamp?

Tags: javascript, json, http

I'm trying to use an API from bitstamp to fetch a currency trading price on my webpage.

I have researched this problem, but I still cannot get it to work as it always returns `ERROR`

The link used is `https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/` and the response should be `last`

Here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", true);
xhr.send();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
function processRequest(e) {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     window.alert(response.last);
}
else {
    window.alert("ERROR");
} }
```

Comment: if I am not wrong, you should be seeing below error in your browser console - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: Yeah this is true. But how can I deal with it

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of the error details contained in the developer console, and the full error message from bitstamp.  Those are essential parts of an HTTP request question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsonRes= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      if (jsonRes.hasOwnProperty('last')) {
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  jsonRes.last;
                 alert(jsonRes.last);
}
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
<p>last attribute is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Comment: you got ERROR ?

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: just for the record, why did you open the <p id > tag, if u are not using it anywhere?

Comment: Yep you're right, I was planning to use one but then again you wanted an alert not a "p tag"

Comment: Could you please show me the solution with the „p Tag“, thank you sir.

Comment: Would be great.. need it for my next step

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js">
//none secure web page ?
    jQuery.get("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", function (data, status)
    {
        // use response here; jQuery passes it as the first parameter
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        window.alert(response.last);
            console.log("MyFunc: " + "response : " + response + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It seems correct, but it doesn't work... what am I doing the wrong way?

Comment: It is correct @Trrrrrrrrrr ;O). must be your URL, try "http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/" (taken off the s of https), hmm it does not have a none secure web page, I tried it, only secure https .

Comment: Have you lost internet access or having problems with your firewall ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", true);
xhr.send();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

function processRequest(e) { 
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      window.alert(response.last);
    } else {
      window.alert("ERROR");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in your logic. First check if request is completed (readyState == 4) and only after check the status-code and print your desired value or ERROR.