# Issue fetching data from API using bearer code in React

Tags: reactjs, authorization

I'm trying to make an API call using react. My code looks similar to the below one. When I try it, I'm getting an logging error(404-page not found).

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {

          headers: new Headers({
             Authorization: "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }),
          method: "GET",
          mode: 'no-cors'
        })
```

Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the content-type property. The body of the request is empty, that's why it fails.

[W3C - Content-Type Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

> The purpose of the Content-Type field is to describe the data
>   contained in the body fully enough that the receiving user agent can
>   pick an appropriate agent or mechanism to present the data to the
>   user, or otherwise deal with the data in an appropriate manner.

**UPDATE:** 
If you are using Chrome to test it, please read this thread [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err/38000615#38000615)

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     res : {},
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
             headers: new Headers({
             Authorization: "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          }),
          method: "GET"
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ res: json}));
 };
 
  render() {
    return (<div> { JSON.stringify(this.state) } </div>);
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I removed it and tried, it did not work got the same issue.

Comment: @sudhach That's because the response has CORS headers and you are sending a no-cors request, remove it too.

Comment: Removed it, got the following error,Failed to load https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.feed:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: @sudhach I guess that you are using Chrome to test it so read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err/38000615#38000615

Comment: Thank you. It worked by adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' chrome extension